# How to use #define variable as method parameter in objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsmanagedobjectcontext, define-syntax

I'm pretty new to Objective-C and what I want to do is have define variables in the `EntityNameConstants.h` file where I store all the Entity Names.

And the I will use all the defines in repository for all the methods related to the ManagedObjectContext.

EG. This is in the .h file

```
define ENTITY_USER_PICTURE = @"UserPicture"
```

and in repository i want to use this constants as following

```
UserPicture *userPicture = (UserPicture *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_USER_PICTURE
                                                                            inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

but I cannot do this, it gives me Parse Issue error.

Am I doing anything wrong in here?

Comment: Did you put the hash (#) before define? Can you paste the output error?

Comment: Keep in mind that Objective-C is "C", it is a strict superset. Everything that works in "C" also works in Objective-C.

Comment: There's really no good reason to use a define rather than a const string for that purpose.

Comment: Hi the syntax for define is #define ENTITY_USER_PICTURE @"UserPicture".  and Hi Jesse i see what you are saying but in that case for const i need .h and .m file where i have only .h file where i declare only #define. so i don't want to introduce new class for constants. is there any alternative?

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax for a `define` is:

```
#define VARIABLE @"value"
```

Comment: Note: there is no equal sign.

Comment: Sorry the syntax is  #define ENTITY_USER_PICTURE @"UserPicture" i wnat to use this as variable a parameter insertNewObjectForEntityForName